# my_dataframe.new_column = value?

Tags: python, pandas

I just run into an odd Pandas behavior. Say I do:

```
import string
import random
m_size = (4,3)
num_mat = np.random.random_integers(0,10, m_size)
my_cols = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(matrix.shape[1])]
mydf =  pd.DataFrame(num_mat, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

print mydf

   A   B   C
0  6   6   7
1  9  10   4
2  0  10   7
3  1   3  10
```

if I now do:

```
mydf.D = 4
```

I would expect it to create a column `D` filled with the value 4, but the **entries** of `mydf` did not change:

```
print mydf

   A   B   C
0  6   6   7
1  9  10   4
2  0  10   7
3  1   3  10
```

Why? I did **not** get any warnings nor errors, so what did `mydf.D = 4` do?

This is all with the most recent stable version of pandas (0.11.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although pandas allows you to *read* columns with `df.Col`, this is apparently just a shorthand for `df['Col']`, and the shorthand doesn't work for creating new columns.  You need to do `mydf['D'] = 4`.

I find this unfortunate because I often try to do just as you did.  The insidious part is that it actually creates an ordinary Python attribute called `D` on the dataframe object; it just isn't actually added as a column.  So you have to be sure to delete that attribute, or it will hide the column even if you later add it correctly:

```
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=["A", "B"])
>>> d
          A         B
0 -0.931675  1.029137
1 -0.363033 -0.227672
2  0.058903 -0.362436
>>> d.Col = 8
>>> d.Col    # Attribute is there
8
>>> d['Col']    # But it is not a columns, just a simple attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    d['Col']
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1906, in __getitem__
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\core\generic.py", line 570, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1383, in get
    _, block = self._find_block(item)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1525, in _find_block
    self._check_have(item)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1532, in _check_have
    raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named Col'
>>> d['Col'] = 100    # Create a real column
>>> d.Col    # Attribute blocks access to column
8
>>> d['Col']    # Column is available via item access
0    100
1    100
2    100
Name: Col, dtype: int64
>>> del d.Col    # Delete the attribute
>>> d.Col     # Columns is now available as an attribute (!)
0    100
1    100
2    100
Name: Col, dtype: int64
>>> d['Col']    # And still as an item
5: 0    100
1    100
2    100
Name: Col, dtype: int64
```

It can be somewhat surprising to see that `d.Col` "only works after you delete it" --- that is, after you do `del d.Col`, subsequently reading `d.Col` will actually give you the column.  This is just because of how Python `__getattr__` works, but it's still a little unintuitive in this situation.

Comment: I see. I presume/hope that the plan is to eventually implement this functionality. I guess I should report this on Github.

Comment: @user815423426: You could give it a shot.  I think there are legitimate reasons to be cautious about it, though.  The problem is that dotted-name attribute access occupies the same namespace as methods, so with this approach you can't add a column that has the same name as a DataFrame method (e.g., "sum"), and in fact you risk overwriting methods with your data, which would definitely be bad.

Comment: Also when it would be possible to create new columns through df.Col, it would make it impossible to monkey-patch DataFrame class. Many people add their own methods to the DataFrame class. Consider df.Col as a convenience method for interactive use, for production code use the data access methods (see note on top of http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), also interesting https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3056